# strange result with JPEG compression

Tags: matlab, image-processing, huffman-code

I want to implement the JPEG compression by using MATLAB. Well at the point where the symbols' probabilities (Huffman coding) are calculated i can see some NEGATIVE values. I am sure that this is not correct!!! if someone can give some help or directions i would really appreciate it. Thank all of you in advance. I use MATLAB R2012b. Here is the code:

```
clc; 
clear all;
a = imread('test.png');
b = rgb2gray(a);
b = imresize(b, [256 256]);
b = double(b);
final = zeros(256, 256);

mask = [1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1 
        1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0
        1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0
        1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0
        1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0
        1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0
        1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
        1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0];

 qv1 = [ 16   11   10   16   24   40   51   61
         12   12   14   19   26   58   60   55
         14   13   16   24   40   57   69   56
         14   17   22   29   51   87   80   62
         18   22   37   56   68  109  103   77
         24   35   55   64   81  104  113   92
         49   64   78   87  103  121  120  101
         72   92   95   98  112  100  103   99];

t = dctmtx(8);
DCT2D = @(block_struct) t*block_struct.data*t';
msk = @(block_struct) mask.*block_struct.data;

for row = 1:8:256
   for column = 1:8:256
       x = (b(row:row+7, column:column+7));
       xf = blockproc(x, [8 8], DCT2D);
       xf1 = blockproc(xf, [8 8], msk);
       xf1 = round(xf1./qv1).*qv1;
       final(row:row+7, column:column+7) = xf1;
   end 
end

[symbols,p] = hist(final,unique(final));
bar(p, symbols);
p = p/sum(p); %NEGATIVE VALUES????
```

Comment: Did the answer solve the problem or help at all?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have the outputs of `hist` (`symbols` and `p`) swapped.  The probability should be calculated from the bin counts, which is the first output of `hist`.

> `[nelements,centers] = hist(data,xvalues)` returns an additional row vector, `centers`, indicating the location of each bin center on the x-axis. To plot the histogram, you can use `bar(centers,nelements)`.

In other words, instead of your current line,

```
[symbols,p] = hist(final,unique(final));
```

just use,

```
[p,symbols] = hist(final,unique(final));
```

Also, `final` is a matrix rather than a vector, so `nelements` will be a matrix:

> If `data` is a matrix, then a histogram is created separately for each column. Each histogram plot is displayed on the same figure with a different color.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. I think that know is more clear. I will keep trying

Comment: Responses tend to be quick around here. Anyway, let me know if you run into other problems or if you get it working.  Glad to help.

Comment: Well if i understood correctly (watching the code's results as well), The symbols will be the probability. I tried to use the symbols but during compilation an error such this occurred:

Error using huffmandict (line 71)
The symbol input must be a vector

Error in JPEG2 (line 49)
   [dict,avglen] = huffmandict(symbols,p);

Comment: Well if i understood correctly (watching the code's results as well), the symbols will be the probability. I tried to use the symbols but during compilation an error such this occurred:

Error using huffmandict (line 71)
The symbol input must be a vector

Error in JPEG2 (line 49)
   [dict,avglen] = huffmandict(symbols,p);

After some google research i found that the following command: symbols = symbols/sum(symbols), will solve the problem. Indeed the above error didn't appear again and the histogram was more compact than before, without different colors.

Comment: But another error appeared related with the first question:

Error using huffmandict (line 85)
Probability of an input symbol cannot be negative

Error in JPEG2 (line 49)
   [dict,avglen] = huffmandict(symbols,p);

The symbols doesn't contain any negative value. On the other hand, the p vector contains a lot of negative values, which i think this causes the error.

Comment: Yes, this is what I said in my answer.  You have `p` and `symbols` swapped on the line when you call `hist`.  **Switch them** and you don't have to do `symbols = symbols/sum(symbols)` like you said and your call to `huffmandict` won't be broken.

Comment: Forgive me for my question but what do you mean by 'swapped on the line'? Maybe swapped based on rows or something else? Is possible for you to be more as specific? For instance, the 'p' is 1x433 and the 'symbols' is 433x768.

Comment: Just updated my answer to be more clear about what I mean by swapping the outputs of a function.